# How do i find a closed form expression for $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(x-1)^k}{k+1}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, closed-form, geometric-series

How do I Find a closed form expression for :

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(x-1)^k}{k+1}$$

Note :I have no idea how to do that, I am bad at evaluating series when we cannot use some standard series to do it.

Thank you for any help

Comment: Think about integration

Comment: Alternatively, just multiply by (x-1) and get some self-symmetry

Comment: If you multiply by $(x-1)$ and substitute $y=x-1$, does it look like a common power series?

Comment: See [Mercator series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series).

Comment: Sure the sum is not on every $k\geqslant0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We begin with the finite geometric series $f_n(z) = \frac{z^{n+1} - 1}{z-1} = \sum_{k=0}^n z^k. $  Integration term-by-term with respect to $z$ then gives $ \int f_n(z) \, dz = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{z^{k+1}}{k+1} = z \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{z^k}{k+1}.$   Therefore,  $S = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(x-1)^k}{k+1} = \frac{1}{x-1} \int_{z=0}^{x-1} f_n(z) \, dz .$   This integral does not have an elementary closed form antiderivative.  It is, however, expressible as an incomplete beta function:   $S = -\frac{\log(2-x) + {\rm B}(x-1;n+2,0)}{x-1}.$ That's the best you can really hope to do, but it's really no different than writing $S$ in terms of the integral of $f_n$.  If this question is part of a larger question and you are certain it is posed correctly, chances are that you are approaching the solution incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum \frac{(x-1)^k}{k+1}=\\\frac{1}{x-1}\sum \frac{(x-1)^{k+1}}{k+1}\\$$
Suppose 
\begin{align}
S &= 1+(x-1)+(x-1)^2+(x-1)^3 +...+(x-1)^k \\
&=(x-1)^0+(x-1)+(x-1)^2+(x-1)^3 +...+(x-1)^k
\end{align}
now integral of s:
\begin{align}
\int Sdx &= \int ((x-1)^0+(x-1)+(x-1)^2+(x-1)^3 +...+(x-1)^k) \\
&= (x-1)+\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}+\frac{(x-1)^3}{3}\frac{(x-1)^4}{4}+...+\frac{(x-1)^{k+1}}{k+1}
\end{align}
 note that S is sum of geometric progression

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(x-1)^{k}}{k+1}\text{ and } 1 < x < 2$,
$$F(x) + C= \int f(x)\ dx = \int \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(x-1)^{k}}{k+1}\ dx$$
$$= \sum_{k=0}^n \int\frac{(x-1)^{k}}{k+1}\ dx = \sum_{k=0}^n (x-1)^{k+1}$$$$ =(x-1)\cdot\sum_{k=0}^{n}(x-1)^k = (x-1)\cdot\frac{(x-1)^{n+1} - 1}{(x-1) - 1}$$
$$f(x) = \frac{d}{dx}F(x) = \frac{\big[(n+1)(x-1) - (n+2)\big](x-1)^{n+1} - 1}{(x-2)^2}$$